# On click show one list and hide other list using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one tabular structure using div, where am showing data. If i will click on one row then am hiding that row and showing some content in place of that. It is similar like google inbox concept, where on click of on row it will show the mail content there only.

But in inbox on click on another email it first hiding the already expanded email content and then showing the other one. In my case am able to show the content on click of the row but unable to hide already shown content div.

This is my code, I have used ng-show and ng-hide along with ng-click.

```
<div class="surveyList" ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys">
  <span class="checkbox" ng-hide="showDetails"></span>
  <div class="toogleSurvey" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" ng-click="showDetails=!showDetails" ng-hide="showDetails">
    <div>{{survey.Name}}</div>
    <div>{{survey.Type}}</div>
    <div class="hidden-xs">{{survey.SurveyReference}}</div>
    <div class="hidden-xs">{{survey.CreatedDate}}</div>
    <div class="hidden-xs SurveyLastChild">{{survey.Status}}</div>
    <div class="hidden-xs surveyListTool"  ng-show="hoverEdit">
      <a class="editSurvey"><img src="images/edit_normal.png" /></a>
      <a class="deleteSurvey"><img src="images/delete_normal.png" /></a>
      <a class="exportSurvey"><img src="images/export_normal.png" /></a>
      <a class="menuSurvey"><img src="images/menu_normal.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="surveyDetailsBox" ng-show="showDetails" ng-click="showDetails=!showDetails">
    <div class="surveyDetailHead">
      <p class="surveyTitle">{{survey.Name}}</p>
      <div class="surveyDetailHeadTool">
        <a class="editSurvey"><img src="images/edit_normal.png" /></a>
        <a class="deleteSurvey"><img src="images/delete_normal.png" /></a>
        <a class="exportSurvey"><img src="images/export_normal.png" /></a>
        <a class="menuSurvey"><img src="images/menu_normal.png" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On click on `div.toogleSurvey` am showing `div.surveyDetailsBox` and it goes reverse also.

Comment: Any js fiddle or plunker working example ?

Comment: Can you post `hoverIn()` and `hoverOut()` functions? Please, add a plunker with the example.

Comment: This concept is similar to the google inbox. If u check that then you will come know the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way.

use ng-click and call a controller function passing the survey object like

```
<div class="toogleSurvey" ng-click="showSurveyDetailsBox(survey)">
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.showSurveyDetailsBox = function(surveyobj)
{
  $scope.surveyobjectForDetailsBox = surveyobj;
  $scope.showSurveyDetails = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("myctrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp"> 
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
   <div>
     <div class="toogleSurvey" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" ng-click="showDetails=!showDetails" ng-hide="showDetails">
      Click on toogleSurvey
 </div>
    
      <div class="surveyDetailsBox" ng-show="showDetails" ng-click="showDetails=!showDetails">
 Click on surveyDetailsBox
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```